# Using jackson deserialising a property which can be List of object or the object

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

My lib is calling an API which can return either of the following JSON structure -

```
{
  "key_is_same" : {
     "inner" : "val"
  } 
}
```

-or-

```
 {
  "key_is_same" : [{
     "inner" : "val1"
    },
    {
     "inner" : "val2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any annotation in jakson which can handle this and deserializ it into respective type

Comment: I'm sure this comment will not help, but ideally an API contract needs to be fixed. But since you might not have control over the API, you can always parse the json into a Map and then have code to detect the type (List<Map> vs Map) . But this wouldnt be my preffered way. I'd take a look at Jackson custom ObjectMapper which can handle this gracefully. Here's a link telling you how to write a custom deserializer (https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization)

Comment: You wouldn't believe that this API has been exposed by one of the industry leader. Though deserialization is my last resort, I am looking for an annotation which can handle this. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for the [`ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY) deserialization feature.

> Feature that determines whether it is acceptable to coerce non-array (in JSON) values to work with Java collection (arrays, `java.util.Collection`) types. If enabled, collection deserializers will try to handle non-array values as if they had "implicit" surrounding JSON array. This feature is meant to be used for compatibility/interoperability reasons, to work with packages (such as XML-to-JSON converters) that leave out JSON array in cases where there is just a single element in array.
>
> Feature is disabled by default.

It could be enabled either in `ObjectMapper`:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);
```

Or via the [`@JsonFormat`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) annotation:

```java
@JsonFormat(with = Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
private List<Foo> oneOrMany;
```

---

For illustration purposes, consider the following JSON documents:

```
{
  "oneOrMany": [
    {
      "value": "one"
    },
    {
      "value": "two"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "oneOrMany": {
    "value": "one"
  }
}
```

It could be the deserialized to the following classes:

```java
@Data
public class Foo {
    private List<Bar> oneOrMany;
}
```

```java
@Data
public class Bar {
    private String value;
}
```

Just ensure the feature is enabled in your `ObjectMapper` or your field is annotated with `@JsonFormat(with = Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)`.

---

And in case you are looking for the equivalent feature for serialization, refer to [`WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `Object` as your data type for the property which is dynamic. So Here is my sample.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class MainObject {

    private Object key_is_same;

    public Object getKey_is_same() {
        return key_is_same;
    }

    public void setKey_is_same(Object key) {
        this.key_is_same = key;
    }

    public static class KeyObject {
        private String inner;

        public String getInner() {
            return inner;
        }

        public void setInner(String inner) {
            this.inner = inner;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String...s) throws JsonProcessingException {
        MainObject main = new MainObject();
        KeyObject k = new KeyObject();
        k.setInner("val1");
        main.setKey_is_same(k);

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(main));

        main.setKey_is_same(Arrays.asList(k, k));
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(main));

        public static void main(String...s) throws IOException {
        MainObject main = new MainObject();
        KeyObject k = new KeyObject();
        k.setInner("val1");
        main.setKey_is_same(k);

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(main));

        main.setKey_is_same(Arrays.asList(k, k));
        System.out.println(om.writeValueAsString(main));

        // Deserialize
        MainObject mainWithObject = om.readValue("{\"key_is_same\":{\"inner\":\"val1\"}}", MainObject.class);
        MainObject mainWithList = om.readValue("{\"key_is_same\":[{\"inner\":\"val1\"},{\"inner\":\"val1\"}]}", MainObject.class);
        if(mainWithList.getKey_is_same() instanceof java.util.List) {
            ((java.util.List) mainWithList.getKey_is_same()).forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
    }

}
```

**Output**

```
{"key_is_same":{"inner":"val1"}}
{"key_is_same":[{"inner":"val1"},{"inner":"val1"}]}
```

Comment: This answer is opposite to what I asked, Actually I am looking for deserialization of the JSON with two very odd schemas.

Comment: You can deserize using the above object and you can check `Object instanceof List`